# Submit Javascript variable PLUS form data to ASP.NET

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have this code:

```
var myArray = new Array();
var counter = 0;
function addElementToForm(value){
    counter ++;
    if (counter < 10)
    {
        $("#cheese").append(value + '<input type="number" value="0"><br />');
        myArray.push(counter + value);
    }
};
```

I have an ASP.NET form on the same page, in the same action of the sumbit button for the form, I want to be able to access myArray from the codefile as well!!

Comment: take a hidden control and store your array value in that and add runat="server" to your hidden control and access it from codebehind.Is that what you need?

Comment: how do i add the data to the hidden control, jst id.value = .... ;

Comment: yes,you can call as hiddencontrolid.value

Comment: cheers man, the best answer i've had from stack overflow so far!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a hidden control and make it as `runat="server"` and try to keep the array value in the hidden control and access it from the codebehind file.